# Close Twitter Oauth login popup and redirect with callback to parent

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, popup

I'm implementing the Twitter oauth with Java in a website and I have a problem with the Login popup.

I open the authorization URL in a Popup window and when the user finish with the login proccess, Twitter redirects to the Callback URL in the Popup. I need to know, if it is possible to close the Popup and redirects to the callback URL in the parent page.

Comment: Actually, I was using the Java API to connect with Twitter in the Back-End and get the Tokens. Then I used javascript in the front-end to manage the pop up window that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution.
I posted in Twitter developer forums as well.
This is what I did:

I set a timer with a function that is running every second.
In that function I check the popup URL, while I'm out of my domain i can't but when the callBack URL is launched, the window come back to my domain I read de URL and if i can find the oauth_verifier as a field in the URL i close the popup and read the URL to recover the verifier.

```
function loginTwitter(){
    var f = document.forms["MainForm"];   
    var url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=***********";
    var myWindow = window.open(url,"","resizable=yes,width=600,height=400,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes");
    var timer = setInterval(checkWindow, 1000); 

    function checkWindow() {

     try {
         var ur = myWindow.location.href; 

         if (ur.indexOf('oauth_verifier') != -1){

             var verifier = "";

             var token = "";

             clearInterval(timer);

             myWindow.close();

             ur = ur.substring(ur.indexOf('?')+1);

             var urPartes = ur.split('&');

             for (i = 0; i < urPartes.length; i++){

                if (urPartes[i].indexOf('oauth_verifier') != -1){
                   verifier = urPartes[i].split('=')[1];
                }

                if (urPartes[i].indexOf('oauth_token') != -1){
                        token = urPartes[i].split('=')[1];
                }
             }

             f.oauth_verifier.value = verifier;

             f.oauth_token.value = token;

             //here an AJAX call is done with the params in the form to do the final verification against twitter i nthe server

         }

     } catch (e){

     } //end catch     
  }//end function checkWindow
}//end function loginTwitter
```

the try/catch block it is to avoid JS errors for "myWindow.location.href" while I'm trying to access the URL while the popup it is out of my domain.
I know it is not a very good way to do it but i couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: what's f ? what's mywindow ? What the hell ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put some lines that were before in the code.<br/>   f is a var refering to a form and myWindow refers to the previous open window.   `var f = document.forms["MainForm"];  
var url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Sy4DmchND5swTaXTQHlz3cXKoUsd6gGb";  
var myWindow = window.open(url,"","resizable=yes,width=600,height=400,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes");`